# Complex integral stuck on one part

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\int_{C} 4e^zcos(e^z) dz$$ where C is the contour given by $\gamma(t):= (log \pi)\sin t+i \cos t$,for $0 ≤ t≤ \frac{\pi}{2}$ is what I need to evaluate

But the problem is the completion of it.

I understand we're given $\gamma$ and then if we take the derivate:

$\gamma '(t) = (log \pi)\cos t - i \sin t$ and then sub in using

$\int f(\gamma (t)) \gamma '(t) dt$ using the bounds

Now I'm just stuck on how do we evaluate

$$e^{(log \pi)\sin t+i \cos t}$$ and complete the question?

If someone could help this would be really helpful

Comment: Since the integrand is holomorphic, you can just take a simpler path from $i$ to $\ln \pi$. E.g. first go from $i$ to $0$ in a straight line and then from $0$ to $\ln \pi$ in a straight line.

Comment: Find the indefinite integral $\int \cos e^z \, d(e^z)$, then apply the Newton-Leibniz formula.